# Remotely connect to a device to invoke-command using local admin credentials instead of domain authentication

Tags: powershell, invoke-command, powershell-5.1

I need to access a remote device to run commands, but they need to be run as the local admin account. Whenever I use `Get-Credential`, I have to authenticate over the domain, which of course fails if I provide a `.\LocalAdmin` format.

Is there a way to use the remote device's local admin account?

```
#Example code
if (!$cred) {
    $cred = Get-Credential -Message "Enter Privileged Account"
} else {
    Write-Host "Running script as $($cred.UserName)"
}

$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName ExampleComputer -Credential $cred
Enter-PSSession $session

Invoke-Command -Session $session { "do stuff here" }

Exit-PSSession
```

Per Santiago's request, the following error message is what is shown when I provide the username in the `.\LocalAdmin` format:

> New-PSSession : [ExampleComputer] Connecting to remote server ExampleComputer failed
> with the following error message : The user name or password is
> incorrect. For more information,  see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting
> Help topic.

When I provide `ExampleComputer\LocalAdmin` as the format, I get the following error:

> New-PSSession : [ExampleComputer] Connecting to remote server ExampleComputer failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with  errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: We can't sign you in with this credential because your domain isn't available. Make sure your device  is connected to your organization's network and try again. If you previously signed in on this device with another credential, you can sign in with that credential.
>
> Possible causes are:
>
> -The user name or password specified are invalid.
>
> -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
>
> -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
>
> -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
>
> -The client and remote computers are in different domains and
> there is no trust between the two domains. After checking for the
> above issues, try the following:
>
> -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
>
> -Change the authentication method; add
> the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration
> setting or use HTTPS transport.  Note that computers in the
> TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
>
> -For more information
> about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help
> config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting
> Help topic.

Comment: Can you add the error message while authenticating ? also, for username, try using `RemoteComputerName\LocalUser`, I'm not sure if `.\LocalUser` would work

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I've updated the question with the error messages in both scenarios. Hope it helps narrow down things.

Comment: What happens if you use `-Authentication Basic` ?